# Mobicents - SimpleServlet Application Router not routing invite to

Tags: servlets, sip, telephony, telecommunication

I am trying to follow the tutorial at,
http://ben-touron.blogspot.com/2009/11/developping-simple-sip-application-with.html

to create a Simple Servlet using Mobicents. I have configured my dar file and also set up the dar file in the server.xml in Apache Tomcat v6.0

Looked at http://www.java.net/node/699015?force=762 for answers & found none. I shut down the firewall as well :(

**Server.xml**

```
<Service className="org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipStandardService" congestionControlCheckingInterval="-1" darConfigurationFileLocation="file:///E:/Research/SIP/SipServlets/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/conf/dars/mobicents-dar.properties" name="Sip-Servlets" sipApplicationDispatcherClassName="org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.SipApplicationDispatcherImpl" sipStackPropertiesFile="conf/mss-sip-stack.properties">
```

**Dar file**

```
INVITE=("org.example.servlet.sip.SimpleSipServlet", "DAR\:From", "TERMINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0")
```

My application is not getting routed when I call via X-Lite even though my SIP Servlet is initialized. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You were looking at outdated instructions. Take a look at more recent tutorials on Mobicents SIP Servlets:

http://docs.telestax.com/sip-servlets-homepage/